# how to make java byte array to reactJS video

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript

I'm receiveing file from java api server and i have to make it to video in react JS.

java api server makes video file to byte array with `Files.readAllBytes(file)`

and i have to use this video file byte array to make video file at react JS

i have no idea that when byte array passed from java api server, make it to video file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed java api server to send base64 encoded byte array and
did it with base64 string

```
<video src={'data:video/mp4;base64,' + base64-String} />
```